# Sort matrix with variable number of columns in R

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

i would like to sort matrix MM based on column "summ" in ascending order, then descending order for column 1 til column before "summ". Thus if n = 4, then i need sort MM based on column "summ" in ascending order, then descending order for column 1 til 4. My code is:

```
n <- 4
M <- matrix(NA_integer_, nrow=2^n-1, ncol=n)
M <- as.matrix(M)
for (i in 1:(2^n-1))
   M[i, ] <- as.integer(intToBits(i)[1:n])
MM <- data.frame(M[-1,])
MM <- cbind(M,apply(M, 1, sum))
dimnames(MM)[[2]] <- c(paste("item",1:n,sep=""), "summ")
```

my result would like to be following code while i want general solution for n.

```
MMM <- MM[order(MM[,n+1],-MM[,1],-MM[,2],-MM[,3],-MM[,4]),]
      item1 item2 item3 item4 summ
 [1,]     1     0     0     0    1
 [2,]     0     1     0     0    1
 [3,]     0     0     1     0    1
 [4,]     0     0     0     1    1
 [5,]     1     1     0     0    2
 [6,]     1     0     1     0    2
 [7,]     1     0     0     1    2
 [8,]     0     1     1     0    2
 [9,]     0     1     0     1    2
[10,]     0     0     1     1    2
[11,]     1     1     1     0    3
[12,]     1     1     0     1    3
[13,]     1     0     1     1    3
[14,]     0     1     1     1    3
[15,]     1     1     1     1    4
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use a custom function along the lines of the following:

```
CustomOrder <- function(inTable) {
  n <- ncol(inTable)
  Order <- do.call(order, c(data.frame(inTable[, n], inTable[, 1:(n-1)] * -1)))
  inTable[Order, ]
}
```

I would suggest adding some error checking in there, though, and testing it on more than just the sample you've provided here.

Usage would be:

```
CustomOrder(MM)
#       item1 item2 item3 item4 summ
#  [1,]     1     0     0     0    1
#  [2,]     0     1     0     0    1
#  [3,]     0     0     1     0    1
#  [4,]     0     0     0     1    1
#  [5,]     1     1     0     0    2
#  [6,]     1     0     1     0    2
#  [7,]     1     0     0     1    2
#  [8,]     0     1     1     0    2
#  [9,]     0     1     0     1    2
# [10,]     0     0     1     1    2
# [11,]     1     1     1     0    3
# [12,]     1     1     0     1    3
# [13,]     1     0     1     1    3
# [14,]     0     1     1     1    3
# [15,]     1     1     1     1    4
```